# Performance comparison of charAt() method of String vs StringBuilder in Java

Tags: java, string, time, stringbuilder

I understand that [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is faster than [String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) when it comes to operations that require some sort of mutation. However, if I only wish to access **specific characters** and no other operations are required, then is there any performance difference between the `charAt()` methods of both?

As a trivial example, if I needed to print the alternate characters of a string, starting from the first character, is there any preferred way to do it, of the two given below?

```java
// 1
String dummyStr = "fhweyxnqwiynfgHINYUIYIOhuiw12341dfs";
for (int i = 0; i < dummyStr.length(); i += 2) {
    System.out.print(dummyStr.charAt(i));
}

// 2
StringBuilder dummySb = new StringBuilder(dummyStr);
for (int i = 0; i < dummySb.length(); i += 2) {
    System.out.print(dummySb.charAt(i));
}
```

Additionally, are there any benefits/drawbacks of doing it this way (using a `char[]`) instead?

```java
// 3
char[] dummyArr = dummyStr.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < dummyArr.length; i += 2) {
    System.out.print(dummyArr[i]);
}
```

*Please note:*
For this question, I am only concerned with the performance in terms of time, and not bothered about additional memory used. Also, the `System.out.print()` is merely a placeholder operation for the purpose of this example.

Comment: It depends on your data, so if you really want to know if there is *any* difference, **run your own benchmarks** (aka do your own *research*) using actual data matching the scenarios you want to check. However, even if you can measure a difference, I bet it is so small it **makes no difference** to the overall performance of your code, given everything else that's likely going on. This is an example of Premature Optimization, and you should move on and spend your time on something that actually matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `String` and `StringBuilder` are backed by arrays and `charAt()` gets the value at the specified index.

Since `String` is immutable, it must make a defensive copy before returning the array.  So it has some additional overhead.  But imo, this would only be a problem for very large strings or repeated conversion of many strings to arrays.  It all depends how how you are using it.

Comment: Does that mean all 3 methods are essentially the same? Also, if `charAt()` is called multiple times (either in a loop, or at different points in the program), is a fresh array created each time, or does the compiler optimise it or cache the array somehow?

Comment: @KabirKanhaArora the call to `charAt` will not create a fresh array at all, why do you think it would (and FYI, the sources are included in Java, so you can look at what the implementation actually does).

Comment: *Is a fresh array created each time, or does the compiler optimise it or cache the array somehow?*  Why not create two arrays from the same string and see if the references compare?  That should answer your question.